# How to restart a service each hour, in upstart?

Tags: debian, redhat-enterprise-linux, ssh-tunnel, upstart

I have an upstart service defined as:

/etc/init/sshproxy.conf

```
description    "Lenik's secret tunnel thru *.ssh.myserver.com"
author        "谢继雷 (Lenik)"

start on (net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
stop on runlevel[!2345]

script

    # -T disable pseudo-tty allocation
    # -f go to background after login but before command exec
    # -n stdin from /dev/null, must be used when ssh is run in bg.
    # -N no command
    # -D "dynamic" app-level port forwarding.
    sudo -usshproxy ssh -qTfn -ND *:7878 ssh.myserver.com

end script
```

But the ssh tunnel seems to be zombied after some hours, so I want to restart it each hour, how to do it within this .conf file, or should I write another cron.hourly job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than restart the service at fixed intervals, you could restart the service when the connection dies. Pass the [`ServerAliveInterval`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5#DESCRIPTION) option to make ssh detect a broken connection faster.
Use the [`respawn`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#respawn) directive in the Upstart script to have the tunnel restarted automatically. Alternatively, use an ssh tunnel restarting program such as [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/).

Comment: Great information!

Answer (score 5):

While "events generated at timed intervals" is a [planned feature](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) in Upstart, it is not ready to provide that yet. So you should write a simple script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
service sshproxy restart
```

And put it into `/etc/cron.hourly` folder. Don't forget to set an executable bit (`chmod +x /etc/cron.hourly/whatever.sh`), or it will not start.

Comment: Do user cron scripts are run in `sudo` mode?

Comment: No, they are run as the user they belong to, i.e. like if you'd call them manually from terminal when logged in as that user.

Comment: Like most of Upstart, it is a planned feature. It's a really cool idea, but not actually implemented yet.

Comment: @Tim, Upstart is currently replaces `init` nicely, and all of its planned features are, actually, replacing other Unix daemons.

Comment: You can also do put initctl emit a_custom_event in cron, and add or a_custom_event to the start on line in the upstart job